# How to get the fields in an Object via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have an object (basically a VO) in Java and I don't know its type.
I need to get values which are not null in that object.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can use [`Class#getDeclaredFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()) to get all declared fields of the class. You can use [`Field#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)) to get the value.

In short:

```
Object someObject = getItSomehow();
for (Field field : someObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true); // You might want to set modifier to public first.
    Object value = field.get(someObject); 
    if (value != null) {
        System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value);
    }
}
```

To learn more about reflection, check the [Oracle tutorial on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

That said, if that VO is a fullworthy Javabean, then the fields do not necessarily represent **real** properties of a VO. You would rather like to determine the public methods starting with `get` or `is` and then invoke it to grab the real property values.

```
for (Method method : someObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())
        && method.getParameterTypes().length == 0
        && method.getReturnType() != void.class
        && (method.getName().startsWith("get") || method.getName().startsWith("is"))
    ) {
        Object value = method.invoke(someObject);
        if (value != null) {
            System.out.println(method.getName() + "=" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

That in turn said, there may be more elegant ways to solve your actual problem. If you elaborate a bit more about the functional requirement for which you think that this is the right solution, then we may be able to suggest the right solution. There are many, *many* tools available to massage javabeans. There's even a built-in one provided by Java SE in the [`java.beans`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/package-summary.html) package.

```
BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(someObject.getClass());
for (PropertyDescriptor property : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
    Method getter = property.getReadMethod(); 
    if (getter != null) {
        Object value = getter.invoke(someObject);
        if (value != null) {
            System.out.println(property.getName() + "=" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i have to modify the value of the field in object? Modify like gte current value perform something and then add it back to Object?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a quick and dirty method that does what you want in a generic way. You'll need to add exception handling and you'll probably want to cache the BeanInfo types in a weakhashmap.

```
public Map<String, Object> getNonNullProperties(final Object thingy) {
    final Map<String, Object> nonNullProperties = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
    try {
        final BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(thingy
                .getClass());
        for (final PropertyDescriptor descriptor : beanInfo
                .getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            try {
                final Object propertyValue = descriptor.getReadMethod()
                        .invoke(thingy);
                if (propertyValue != null) {
                    nonNullProperties.put(descriptor.getName(),
                            propertyValue);
                }
            } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // handle this please
            } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
                // and this also
            } catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
                // and this, too
            }
        }
    } catch (final IntrospectionException e) {
        // do something sensible here
    }
    return nonNullProperties;
}
```

**See these references:**

- [BeanInfo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) (JavaDoc)
- [Introspector.getBeanInfo(class)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#getBeanInfo%28java.lang.Class%29) (JavaDoc)
- [Introspection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html) (Sun Java
  Tutorial)

Answer (score 4):

> I've an object (basically a VO) in
>   Java and I don't know its type. I need to get values which are not null in that object.

Maybe you don't necessary need reflection for that -- here is a **plain OO design** that might solve your problem:

1. Add an interface `Validation` which expose a method `validate` which checks the fields and return whatever is appropriate.
2. Implement the interface and the method for all VO.
3. When you get a VO, even if it's *concrete* type is unknown, you can typecast it to `Validation` and check that easily.

I guess that you need the field that are null to display an error message in a generic way, so that should be enough. Let me know if this doesn't work for you for some reason.