# Convert POJO to Map without using Apache Commons Beanutils

Tags: java

Without using [Apache Commons Beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html) what is the most simple way to create a method to convert a POJO into a `Map<String,Object>`

Comment: You're trying to convert all fields? So if you have a field `foo` containing `1` and a field `bar` containing a String, you want a `Map` containing `"foo"`->`Integer(1)` and `"bar"`->`"whatever baz"`?

Comment: looking into the docs you provided describe(Object bean) method will help you I guess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2989585/106261

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without an external jar, I think the only way is to *use the dark side of the force* : [**the reflection api**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Not so dark; fear not, Luke.

Comment: Fear leads to anger; anger leads to hate; hate leads to reflection; reflection leads to suffering?