# Catching value of the concatenated variable

Tags: c#

My environment is: W7 Ultimate 64 bits, VS2010 Ultimate, C#, WinForm, target XP and W7.

With the help of @dasblinkenlight, the concatenation on the for loop was very good.
I feel we are making great progress.
As you ca see, we are putting into the array sMntHour[d,h] the string "csv_001_01" if d=1 and h=1 and so on.

This csv_001_01, csv_001_02,.. ; are variables that contains an integer value.

```
csv_001_01=5111;
csv_001_02=236; // This is a sample, because has 365 days in normal year
                // and 366 days in leaf year. "csv_day_hour"
```

Directly we could do this:

```
sMntHour[d,h] = csv_001_01.ToString(); // d is day and h is hour
sMntHour[d,h] = csv_001_02.ToString();
```

As we put the value of this concatenated variable in the array and not the name of the variables?

```
for(int d=1;d<=365;d++) //I'll put the code to not leap years.
{
  for(int h=1; h<=24; h++)
  {
    sMntHour[d,h] = string.Format("csv_{0:000}_{1:00}", d, h)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you rephrase it so that it's easier to understand what you're asking?

Comment: ok! I making changes and go back.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you might want to look at `System.Reflection`. (You want the *value* and not the *name* of the variable.)

Comment: I think he has a list of variables `csv_ddd_hh` (not shown in the question) that he wants to programmatically refer to to set the value at index `[d,h]`. So he is generating the name of each variable in the loop, but wants to know how to access them. // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989560/how-to-get-the-fields-in-an-object-via-reflection

Comment: I can't see any variables called csv_001_01 or csv_001_02 in your code.

Comment: I can't see a question here

Comment: @AnotherUser, correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, you have all the variable names and now you want to get their values.

You could do this using `Reflection` and you can create a dictionary where keys are the variable names and the values are the actual values. It is really hard to help without seeing how these variables are declared, are they fields / properties ? are the private, static ? etc... But something like this should work, in theory:

```
var type = this.GetType();
var values = sMntHour.OfType<string>()
                     .ToDictionary(
                           x => x, 
                           x => (int)type.GetField(x).GetValue(this));
```

Then you can access the values using `values["variable_name"]`

Or if you don't want this, instead if you want to access them using index like `[d,h]` as mentioned in comments, do not store the variable names in the first place instead store the values in your array:

```
var type = this.GetType();
for(int d=1;d<=365;d++) 
{
  for(int h=1; h<=24; h++)
  {
      var name = string.Format("csv_{0:000}_{1:00}", d, h);
      sMntHour[d,h] = (int)type.GetField(name).GetValue(this);
  }
}
```

Ofcourse you need to change the type of `sMntHour`, in order to make it work.

Comment: public static string csv_001_01;

Comment: Thank you @Selman22, this little marvel of knowledge, made a huge difference.