# Fields from type T

Tags: java, reflection

I want to get all the fields and it's values from an object of type T. Say I have:

```
public class Start {

    public void startMethod(){
        Main<GenericType> main = new Main<>();
        main.work(new GenericType());
    }

}
```

Then there's class Main, where I want the fields of GenericType:

```
public class Main<T> {

    public void work(T t){
        // Is there a way to get t's fields and values?
    }

}
```

Comment: Reflection. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989560/how-to-get-the-fields-in-an-object-via-reflection

Comment: T can be of any type ? ... or can't you declare an interface `<T extends SomeInterface>` so that you can access getter methods from that interface ?

Comment: You need to explain the background of what you are trying to do. In many situations you can avoid reflection, and you should if at all possible.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh's answer helped me with my problem. I posted as minimal code as possible because the main problem is a *bit* bigger than the one I posted. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @WashingtonA.Ramos Glad to help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @BalwinderSingh's answer I came to this:

```
public void work(T t){
    for(Field f : t.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
        try {
            f.setAccessible(true);

            String name = f.getName();
            Object value = f.get(object);


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It was simpler than I though at the beginning. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

First,you need to get `Class` of `T`,then through reflection ,you can get all fields.

```
abstract class A<T> {  
    Class<T> clazz;  
    void doGetClass() {  
        Type genType = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();  
        Type[] params = ((ParameterizedType) genType).getActualTypeArguments();  
        this.clazz = (Class<T>) params[0];  
    }
}
```

but you must instantiate the generic type ,like this,instantiate `T` to `String`:

```
class B extends A<String>{  
}
```

then

```
B b = new B();  
b.doGetClass();// b.clazz is String.class
```

Comment: You seem to be complicating things a bit... Just doing `t.getClass()` will give the class object in OP's case...

Comment: You cannot create an instance of generic type using `new T()`,so the object `t` cannot be instantiated

Comment: He is passing the `t` parameter to the method... So you will already have an object of type `T`

Comment: `t` is created by `new GenericType()` which will not work.