# How to get the current node name from a javax.​persistence.​criteria.Path

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, persistence

Is there a way to get the current node name (or the entire chain) for a `Path` instance? As far as I can tell, there is no method within `Path` to do so. I tried the `toString()` method, but that is not overridden in EclipseLink (it gets you the default output: `org.eclipse...PathImpl@331a119a`).

I'm using EclipseLink, so a EclipseLink specific solution is fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I checked the path I wanted to get the name for using the debugger, I noticed the EclipseLink implementation of `Path` has a field called `currentNode` of type `QueryKeyExpression` which has the name I was after. So I wrote a utility method:

```
public static QueryKeyExpression getCurrentNode(Path<?> path) {
  try {
    return (QueryKeyExpression) ReflectionUtils.getValue(path, "currentNode");
  }
  catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
  }
}
```

Which allows me to get the name like:

```
JpaUtils.getCurrentNode(path).getName()
```

See also:

- [How to get the fields in an Object via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989560/how-to-get-the-fields-in-an-object-via-reflection)